# Stating changes involving secrecy in Apache version 2 licence

Tags: apache-2.0

If I use a software licenced under Apache version 2 licence and there is a configuration file where I have to enter a secret key, do I have to state it as a change?

Comment: You don't have to do anything to **use** the software. But if you're **redistributing** the software and have changed a config variable for some reason, well the license would apply to it as much as anything else so yes you would have to.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, the Apache license requires that you state **that** you made modifications, but you are not required to spell out **what** you changed.

Secondly, such requirements of copyright licenses only become effective when you distribute the software further. So, if you only use the software and you don't give it to others, then you are not required to do anything.